# C# : How to convert a local pdf file to a byte [][]

Tags: c#, byte

SITUATION

- Using C# ASP.NET on VS 2008
- I want to

  - Read a pdf file from my local directory (What stream type do I use? Can I use filestream?)
  - Put this pdf file into a byte[][] variable

QUESTIONS

- Being new to C#, I would like suggestion (please explain with code), on how I can achieve this.
- I need to know this to complete my project. Any other inputs will be appreciated.

The code is as follows

```
   byte[][] pdfDoc= new byte[1][];

   byte[] outputDoc = File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:/test.pdf");
```

for (int x = 0; x < pdfDoc.Length; x++)
    {
        pdfDoc[x] = outputDoc;

    }

But it is failing, not able to read the file from the d:/test.pdf location.
Thanks.

Comment: You could take a look at http://pdfbox.apache.org/ . It's actually a Java library but you can port it over to C# (and there's help for that). It's kind of a pain but I believe it will do what you want.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the `byte[][]` variable?

Comment: Maybe windows accepts `D:/` but it really should be `D:\\`

Answer (score 9):

I think this will work for you:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\folder\\myfile.pdf");
```

Comment: When I try this I get the 'FileNotFoundError' ( "Could not find file 'd:\\test.pdf')

Comment: Generally, that means the file is not there.  Is D:\ pointing to a network drive by chance?